# Getting Invalid Column Error in C# with SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL Server 2012 Database. This Database contain a Table name as "Item_Master_List". When I try to insert data into it using SQL Query from C# it gives me an error such as

> **Invalid column name 'FC140101001001000'.**
>   When I try to Insert Only Numeric value in it is was inserted but when i tried to insert some value with some string Characters such as "**FC140101001001000**" it give me error.

Table column name is **"Item_Code"**. and its data type is **"VARCHAR(17)"**.

Any One can guide me about it...

here is the Code

```
cf.con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Item_Master_List (Item_Code) VALUES(FC140101001001000)", cf.con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cf.con.Close();
```

Comment: Table defintion and INSERT statement, please!

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you this error?

Comment: single quotes to the value in `'FC140101001001000'`

Comment: Thanks Ameya Deshpande. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your varchar value in single quote then your query shall look like

```
"INSERT INTO Item_Master_List (Item_Code) VALUES('FC140101001001000')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to insert it using parameters,
should look something like this. I might have made some typing errors since I typed it in a normal text editor and im used to the auto fill feature of visual studio.

```
cf.con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Item_Master_List (Item_Code) VALUES(@value)", cf.con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar, 17).Value = "FC140101001001000";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cf.con.Close();
```